# crash on the GPU with {inc,set}_subtensor and broadcasting the value

Tags: neural-network, theano, keras

I am fine-tuning vgg16 network with keras 2.0.2 and theano 0.9.0 as backend on Windows10 64bit Anaconda 2 as this blog:https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

I find someone else had the same issue in the pull requests and it was fixed by changing a few lines of code (link: https://github.com/Theano/Theano/pull/2075). However , that's an old version of theano.(the pr was in 2014) . Theano 0.9.0 have already change the code and I still have this problem

every time I run the last line(i.e. model .fit_generator) , it shows that everything works fine until the last of first epoch. That's when exactly GPU always crash

```
model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        samples_per_epoch=2000,
        nb_epoch=50,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        nb_val_samples=400)
```

And here is the error message:

> CudaNdarray_CopyFromCudaNdarray: need same dimensions for dim 0,
>   destination=32, source=16Apply node that caused the error:
>   GpuIncSubtensor{Set;::, ::, int64:int64:,
>   int64:int64:}(GpuAlloc{memset_0=True}.0,
>   GpuElemwise{mul,no_inplace}.0, Constant{1}, Constant{225},
>   Constant{1}, Constant{225})Toposort index: 143

Comment: It's probably something with `Theano` but I think that setting `samples_per_epoch=2016` should help.

Comment: Thanks! I got it. Because 2000%32=16, the last batch of every epoch is 16, not 32. That's why the error says :destination=32, source=16